# Delete Row From Gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblEmpID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1");  //This is Table Id load on Label1

    conn.Open();

    string cmdstr = "delete from LUMHS_CHALLAN_FEE where ID=@ID";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblEmpID.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

    ShowStudentInfo();   /back to load Grid view Function
}
```

I want to delete row from gridview and i wrote this code but row can not delete Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Is your ID integer or string?
If its integer try convert.toInt32(lblEmpID.Text); please